# Ошибки при установке пакетов с помощью npm

Tags: node.js, npm

Установил NODE.js, далее устанавливаю при помощи npm пакет jquery.. Всё в ошибках. Аналогичная ситуация при установке других пакетов.. Причину не нашёл. На компе установлен OpenServer, PHPStorm.

```
Ronin@Work-PC MINGW64 /c/OpenServer/domains
$ node -v
v6.10.1

Ronin@Work-PC MINGW64 /c/OpenServer/domains
$ npm -v
3.10.10

Ronin@Work-PC MINGW64 /c/OpenServer/domains
$ npm install jquery
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "jquery"
npm ERR! node v6.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 74.122.238.10:8080
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\OpenServer\domains\npm-debug.log

Ronin@Work-PC MINGW64 /c/OpenServer/domains
$
```

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, система Win7 64 разрядная..

Comment: npm не знает про jquery - это не пакет, не модуль, а один большой-большой файл *.js Его просто забирают с сайта JQuery и кладут в какую-нибудь папку проекта.

Comment: я же не выдумал эту строку.. на самом деле строка должна иметь вид $ npm i -S jquery$1 .. Я написал упрощённый вариант.. В обучающем видео, этот процесс назывался, установка пакета jquery и там он установился без ошибок..

Comment: А вы сообщение об ошибке прочитали?

Comment: Ну, я пошёл посмотреть в этих ваших энторнетах - действиельно, говорят, что раньше такое было, до версии 1.11. Потом зачем-то её устанавливали с помощью bower, а потом и это прекратилось. Правда, я не стал вникать - зачем это вообще нужно было.

Comment: Конечно же, пробовал различные варианты решения данной ошибки.. И только потом озвучил вопрос здесь..

Comment: а какая nodejs у вас установлена? отсюда https://nodejs.org/en/download/ ?

Comment: Да, скачано правильно, только предыдущая версия.. Обновил до настоящей, результат тот же..

Comment: Ну судя по логам проблема с доступом к интернету. Надо смотреть настройки сети.

Comment: Как бы да.. с сетью.. Но это только у npm проблемы с сетью.. Почему, не известно.. Эксперты! Может быть, будут практические предложения, для решения моей проблемы?